# Choosing a different optimizer when running QAOA in qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming, optimization, qaoa

I am trying to reproduce the QAOA example from https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/qaoa.html and learn how to opt for a different optimizer.

The relevant block in the example is (towards the end of the example):

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize


expectation = get_expectation(G, p=1)

res = minimize(expectation, 
                      [1.0, 1.0], 
                      method='COBYLA')
res
```

This effectively calls for COBYLA from scipy. However, in qiskit.algorithms.optimizers we can see a lot of other options: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.algorithms.optimizers.html

At the moment, for the block of code given above I cannot figure out how to change my optimizer. Say I want to apply ADAM or GradientDescent or SPSA. It is not clear to me how I can do that since just passing the argument 'ADAM' (for example) as below

```
res = minimize(expectation, 
                          [1.0, 1.0], 
                          method='ADAM')
```

give a `ValueError: Unknown solver ADAM` error. I get the corresponding error when I try other optimizers too.

How can I deal with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `optimizers` in `Qiskit` need to be instantiated then you can call their `minimize()` method. e.g.

```
from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import SPSA

opt = SPSA(maxiter=300)
res = opt.minimize(expectation, [1.0, 1.0])
```

So instead of the optimizer internally being created via a name passed to the `method` argument of scipy (where name is one of the optimizers available via scipy) here you create an instance and configure it via the constructor parameters, and use the minimize method on that instance.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  The precise code is this though:
```spsa = SPSA(maxiter=n)```
```result = spsa.optimize("no of qubits", "expectation/loss", "initial point")```

Comment: The `minimize()` method is is newer versions of Qiskit >= 0.19 and `optimize()` is deprecated since version 0.19 and will be removed shortly. Your code will work in current versions, but in 0.19 and above would emit a deprecation warning telling you to use the `minimize` method instead https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/e5087294007550ac3c2a3691e510de204fc98fac/qiskit/algorithms/optimizers/optimizer.py#L301-L307

Comment: Hmmm... looking over SPSA it overrides `optimize` and does not itself emit a deprecation warning - the intent is to remove `optimize()` entirely so using `minimize` which mimics the scipy interface, is recommended for Qiskit >= 0.19. If you are using an older version then only `optimize` exists so beware when you upgrade as if you skip through versions when upgrading you may miss deprecation messages such as this.

Comment: changing from SPSA to ADAM does not work. Why is that? Is there not a "unified" way to try out different optimizers without changing the code?

Comment: @Marion Note that some algorithms like Gradient Descent or ADAM, if I remember correctly, may require gradient information, which you must provide to them